# Trying to manipulate an array with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I did not want to ask, but I am still quite new to PHP and I am stuck.

I have a comma separated list stored in MySQL; Blue, 12, Red, 15 etc.
I can bring it out and do most of what I want, but I am confused on how to proceed.
Ultimately, I would like to change the output of the data from

`Blue, 12, Red, 15,`

to

`Blue => 12, Red => 15` (without the last comma) So I can use the data in a program I am attempting to build.

Currently, I am able to achieve: 
`Blue, => 12, => Red, => 15,`

Code:

```
$result = $con->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $id                 = $row['id'];
   $type               = $row["dataname"];
   $datas = $type;
  eval( "\$test = array (" . $datas . ");") ;
 foreach($test as $test) 
{
 echo "<option name='$test'>$test , =></option>";
}
}
}
```

Using the desired output, I will be able to input data from a form to create an SVGGraph.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Can you please post the output of `var_dump($datas)`?

Comment: Split the string on commas, array_walk to trim the spaces from the values, array_chunk with a value of 2 to split the names and numbers giving a 2d array; then use array_combine() with array_column() for columns 0 and 1 to create the key/value pairs

Comment: Using `eval` there is quite nonsense. _“I have a comma separated list stored in MySQL”_ – _that’s_ the point where you should begin to improve on thing, by properly _normalizing_ your database data structure.

Comment: Use `str_replace()` to remove the commas. `$test = str_replace(',', '', $tests);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using eval is just the worst.

Here is how I would do it while keeping to your code as much as possible:

```
$result = $con->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $id                 = $row['id'];
        $type               = $row["dataname"];
        $datas = $type;

        $res = array();
        $arr = explode(",", str_replace(" ","",$datas));
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i+=2) {            
            $res[$arr[$i]] = $arr[$i + 1];
        }

        foreach($res as $key=>$value)
        {
            echo "<option name='$value'>$key , =></option>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great. However, I changed this a bit to do more of what I needed (sorry, it was not correct in my OP):

 `echo "$key  => $value, ";`

Now, everything is in place, but I cannot seem to eliminate the last comma, even when using `$value = rtrim($value,',');` because I am already telling the code to add the `","` in.

Comment: I got it! Thank you!

I combined the foreach loop inside of a new variable:

` foreach($res as $key=>$value){ $str .= $key . ' => ' . $value . ' ,'; }} } $str = rtrim($str, ','); echo $str  `

Comment: you are welcome! if my answer was right, please mark it as such!

Answer (score 2):

Ok so first off, I would try storing this information in separate rows in the future, comma separated lists are for when we do not have databases (simple text files for example).

But to answer your question (assuming result is the string of separated values):

```
$result = explode(',', $result);
$output = [];
for($i = 0;$i < count($result);$i=$i+2){
    array_push($output, $result[i] => $result[i+1]);
}
//output:
$str = ""
foreach($output as $key => $value){
    str .= $key . ' => ' . $value . ' ,';
}
$str = rtrim($str, ',');
echo $str //this will be your output
```

Comment: Misinterpreted the question, added. Thanks

Comment: I used part of your solution with another solution to achieve my final  result. Thank you.

Comment: @mcdonaldjosh: Sweet =)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try **not to use eval** - [it is dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php).:)

Second, try to get all the data you need into one big string. Then you can use the [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) PHP function to convert the string into individual elements. And the last thing you would do is to simply iterate over the array and assign the first item as a key and the second item as an element into yet another array.

I will leave the actual implementation to you as an excercise in your PHP coding skills.:)

Answer (score 0):

Please dont use eval. You nearly always can avoid it and is dangerous.
Here is a solution which works without eval:

```
$result = $con->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $type = $row["dataname"];  // Thats our comma-seperated list, right?
        $arr = explode(',', $type); // Make $type to array
        array_pop($arr); // Delete last element because its empty

        // We go through the array with step = 2
        // because the first is always the key and the second the value
        for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i += 2) 
        {
             echo "<option name='$arr[$i+1]'>$arr[$i] , =></option>";
        }
    }
}
```

**Why eval is evil:**
Whatever is in the string is evaled as code from your script with all rights the script has incuding file-access and so on. Since the string for your eval comes from the database you cant even be absolutely sure that it is no bad code you are executing when using eval.
Furthermore eval is bad when it comes to debugging things.
And at the end: Why producing overhead with stuff you can avoid?
It is in general recognized as bad style when using eval because of all this reasons. Better you never get used to it

Comment: `$arr.pop();` ? You probably spent too much time with JavaScript lately...:)

Comment: Can you explain why eval is dangerous? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
//trim comma from the right
$str = rtrim('Blue, 12, Red, 15,', ',');

//create a helper array
$array = explode(', ', $str);

//arrange elements in the new array
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array) - 1; $i = $i + 2) {
    $new[] = $array[$i] . ' => ' . $array[$i + 1];
}

//output new elements
echo implode(', ', $new);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you go from a string to an array to a string.
If so, it is possible to skip the array by using regex. Depending on the length of your string, creating a huge array may be a problem.

So I came up with those examples:

```
$input = "Blue, 1, Red, 2, Green, 3, Violet, 4,";

// Output: Blue => 1, Red => 2, Green => 3, Violet => 4
echo rtrim(preg_replace('/(([^,]*),([^,]*)),+/', '\2 =>\3,', $input), ',');

// Output <option name="Blue">Blue => 1</option><option name="Red">Red => 2</option><option name="Green">Green => 3</option><option name="Violet">Violet => 4</option>
echo preg_replace('/(\s*([^,]*)\s*,\s*([^,]*)\s*),+/', '<option name="\2">\2 => \3</option>', $input);
```

As you can see, no looping involved.

I hope it helped

**EDIT**

Here is links to visualize the regex

- [First regex](http://jex.im/regulex/#!embed=false&flags=&re=%28%28[%5E%2C]*%29%2C%28[%5E%2C]*%29%29%2C%2B)
- [Second regex](http://jex.im/regulex/#!embed=false&flags=&re=%28%5Cs*%28[%5E%2C]*%29%5Cs*%2C%5Cs*%28[%5E%2C]*%29%5Cs*%29%2C%2B)